# Qgis2web missing layers

Tags: qgis2web

**What I have**
I have 5 layers with the following content

- One with 350 000 points
- One with 300 000 points
- One with 30 000 points
- One with 100 polygons
- One with 25 polygons

**What I'm trying to do**

I want to create a webmap whith the help of qgis2web.

**Problem**

Only the the ones with 30 000 point and the two polygon layers appears when the map os completed.

Is there any limitation to the number of points you can have?

Or am I missing something?

Comment: That sounds like possibly too much data for a webmap using GeoJSON (as qgis2web does). Are you able to host the data and make it available as a WFS?

Comment: Yeah sounds like something like that. Sorry, can’t share the file.

Comment: No, I meant are you able to host it on a private WFS server? That way, the data doesn't all have to be converted into GeoJSON.

Comment: When the map is open in your browser, press F12 to show the dev tools, and then click on the Console tab. Paste any errors you find there into your question above.

Comment: Regarding the WFS. Like with geoserver or did you mean something else?

Comment: Yes, precisely, a private WFS server such as Geoserver.